# What happened to Polish football in 2014?

Tags: football, history

I'm Polish and for my whole life I could just dream of spectacular successes of our national team, like in the 80s. However, about the year 2015 something changed, a lot. Our team started to mean something in the world's football. My question is: **why was so**?

I know Polish players started playing in not-so-shameful European clubs, like Borussia, Bayern, Arsenal and of course it mattered a lot but is it really a concidence that a sufficient number of them played in such clubs and it was enough to form a quite strong national team? In Poland much praise went down on Adam Nawałka, the manager of the team. In fact, his team didn't consist of stars only, he found some players from the Polish league.

Maybe it was money which appeared in the Polish league and infrastructure and level of schooling improved? Maybe Poland for some reason became interesting for foreign headhunters? I've got no idea.